# Monitor Kafka Consumer Metrics with JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, jmx, metrics, prometheus

I try to export Kafka metrics per JMX to Prometheus and display them with Grafana, but I´m struggling to get the Consumer metrics (to be more precise this one:

kafka.consumer:type=ConsumerFetcherManager,name=MaxLag,clientId=([-.\w]+) )

Everytime I try to fetch this Mbean, it doesn´t even show up. I read all the time that I have to "look into the client", or "I´m looking in the broker metrics, but I need the consumer metrics", but nobody does explain how to do this, so I´m asking you guys if you could help me. Is there some kind of configuration, or special JMX Port to get Consumer metrics or something like that?

The pattern for my config file to look for MBeans:

```
- pattern :  kafka.consumer<type=(.+), name=(.+), client-id=(.+)><>(Count|Value) 
  name: kafka_consumer_$1_$2
  Labels:
    clientId: "$3"
```

Also, i need to fetch the Metrics with JMX, because i dont have access to the Kafka server.

I´m using this project as an example: https://github.com/rama-nallamilli/kafka-prometheus-monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two things are possible:

A. May be given client already disconnected from Kafka

B. May be this metric is not present on broker. It  might be visible in the JVM application which is running the consumer code. I am not sure but here is how you can check:

1. Restart your consumer application with JMX enabled
2. Use visual vm to connect to the above jvm
3. It should show all the available JMX metrics.
4. If the metrics contain metrics of your choice then you were looking at wrong place (broker). If not then I am wrong.

Comment: It´s like you said. I noticed yesterday, while i tried to hook up VisualVM to a local Kafka. The Lag Metrics are only visible in the consumer, so you cant monitor consumer lag per JMX (at least the way i tried)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have exact configuration but 1 mistake that i can point out in your configuration is that, **name** can not be the matching pattern for consumer metrics.
Try to remove the pattern with this:

```
- pattern :  kafka.consumer<type=(.+), client-id=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
```

For more reference you can check the 
[Apache kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#selector_monitoring)
I am also having the problem for creating a generic pattern for consumer and producer.
Will post here as soon as i get this figured out.

@xBoLLo